# python pyserial won't pull data from port

Tags: python, pyserial

Having trouble with reading from a serial port.

i have a bit of hardware that shows a display with date and time and other details and on the PC you through some software you can bring up a live mirror of the display. what i want to do is log some data at intervals.

using pyserial its trivial to connect to the port, but when reading it using the simplest settings with timeout=none and read size =1 and leaving the port listening indefinitely there is no output from the equipment.

ive tested using virtual port pairs and i can read and write no problem.

Any ideas why there is no output from the serial port?

And i know its the right port because when i open it then it blocks the mirrored display on the PC.

Cheers

Comment: Possibly the hardware requires a command to be sent to it to request its details.  You can use port monitoring software (such as PortMon for Windows) to see what command(s) the display software sends to the device.

Comment: yeah I expected some type of initial trigger. i had a look at PortMon and a couple of other similar ones and I can't get them to "eavesdrop" while the PC and the hardware communicate. once the monitoring program is looking at the port then other communication between the PC and hardware is blocked as usual. Am i doing it wrong? :\ thanks

Comment: PortMon shouldn't block communications: listening in like this is the whole *point* of that program.  If you can't get it to work, you can always do the monitoring the old-fashioned way - connect the TXD pin of that port to the RXD of another port, perhaps on a separate computer, and monitor through the other port.

Comment: sweet so i got the commands in ACSII. i can see what the PC transmits down the serial and the repsonse from the device. But when i go to manually send the identical commands down the serial i just get $e0's back. Would there be a hidden part of the raw string that isn't displayed?

Comment: If you have the oscilloscope then you can connect and check but that is the last bet.